# Compass on a Ringed, Earth-like Planet

Tags: earth-like, fauna, flora, navigation, planetary-rings

Is it necessarily a given that a compass (as they magnetically function on Earth) could be made to function similarly on an alternate, Earth-like, ringed planet?

Another way of asking: is it feasible that the magnetic attributes of another planet could be different than Earth's (possibly making an instrument like a compass nonexistent in that world) and that planet still support flora and fauna similar to Earth?

Comment: smh, google 'Earth's Magnetic Poles'

Comment: In short: Yes. Doesn't need a full answer. As long as the rings aren't made of magnetized material, there's no reason why a compass shouldn't function *as far as I know.* That said, your question comes across slightly unclear. I assume you're asking about a ringed planet like Saturn but with Earth's environment, composition, and atmosphere. If you mean a planet that is a ring, then I don't know.

Comment: I believe they're asking for a way to make compasses not work, rings and other conditions aside.

Comment: In that case it should be stated more clearly. Either way, my comment does explain how to do that then... So... *shrugs*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The requirement of a compass behaving sensibly is that a planet has a reasonably smooth bi-polar magnetic field.  Under such circumstances the lines of force always point towards one of the magnetic poles on the planet's surface, and therefore the compass always points in the same direction.

You also mentioned fauna.  The Earth's magnetic field is a vital part of maintaining the biosphere because it acts to deflect molecule-shredding cosmic rays of varying sorts. Maintaining life without having feasible compasses thus leaves us with a problem to solve.

Non-working compasses and living fauna require either:

- No proper magnetic field, and highly radiation resistant lifeforms
- No proper magnetic field, and subterranean lifeforms
- Something funky about the magnetic field that maintains deflection of cosmic radiation & solar winds, but messes up the compass.

Things that could interfere with the a compass:

- Large, frequent, random deposits of ferromagnetic material causing localised distortions in the EM field (compass won't reliably point in a single direction)
- A multi-polar magnetic field.  That said, this is a tough sell: we don't know if this is possible in the long term, or if the magnetohydrodynamics planetary bodies force a dipole. The planets in the solar system with magnetic fields are not like this
- The planet is iron-poor.  There are no ferromagnetic materials readily available, so no society can invent the compass.

Comment: In the case of having rings of highly ferromagnetic materials circling the globe, could this ring, in theory, offset the magnetic pull of the compass significantly enough to make compasses effectively useless? (Basically, the equivalence of having two magnets messing with a compass, is what I'm getting at.)

Comment: @SoraTamashii the reason magnets make compasses useless is because they are too close to serve as useful reference points. The ring you describe certainly modifies the shape of the magnetic field, making compass reading less straightforward, but still dependent on stable reference points which you can base navigation on.

Comment: My instinct is that any highly magnetized ring material will, itself, be deflected by Earth's magnetic field until it's no longer part of the ring (either ejected or deorbited). I don't have any math to back that up, though.

Comment: A magnetic orbiter would be generally unstable yes.  The only marginally stable orbit is that perpendicular to the magnetic field axis, but it is an unstable equilibrium (and magnetic fields fluctuate and the magnetics poles move).

Comment: @Mark_Anderson - that's a great answer that really helps!  (For anyone confused, this is for a fictional world I'm using in a story.)  I'm leaning along the lines of a world where compasses could not have been invented (most likely due to magnetic disturbance from the rings).  I suppose the question that remains, then, is if such a disturbance would greatly affect the planet's ability to support life, or if that life would have to be substantially different than here on Earth.

Comment: Although, I suppose a gyroscopic compass would still be plausible despite all the weird magnetism, wouldn't it?

Comment: Gyroscopic compasses are a possibility, but they are a difficult technology necessitating a strong manufacturing base (we didn't make them until the 1900's) as you need a frictionless set of joint in the compass such that the gyroscopic forces of the planet's rotation dominate.  So a pre-industrial setting would be fine for this.

Comment: That said, there are a lot of weird tricks you can use for navigation... sunlight ends up polarised by the atmosphere, and looking through calcite crystals can show you that polarisation -- a trick that some people think the vikings actually used. So if you want to get really deep into the worldbuilding you might think though potential fudges to get approximate navigation... 

The rings provide a wonderful reference point in the sky that could solve a lot of the "working out your lat/long" problems that we on Earth spent considerable effort on.

Comment: On the rings specifically, they are actually quite hard to make magnetically active.   It's the tyranny of Newton's Laws: if they are magnetic enough to have interesting effects and push things around, then the rings experience significant magnetic pushes on themselves (from their interactions with the planet's magnetic field).  Under such circumstances it is very hard to get a stable orbit, if not actually impossible.

Comment: Ah, that might be what @Cadence mentioned earlier.  I wonder, though, if there's a reasonably feasible way for the magnetism of the planet and the rings to complement each other - like two "north" magnets repulsing each other just enough that this is what keeps the rings in a certain position around the planet (note that my science could be way off here), and this could account for certain rocks/debris in the rings to show up consistently (like a certain rock always at true south), providing a means of navigation.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use a magnetic compass the way we use it on Earth, you need two conditions:

- a stable bipolar magnetic field
- the axis of the above magnetic field shall be aligned with the rotation axis of the planet.

If the latter condition is [not satisfied](https://ase.tufts.edu/cosmos/view_picture.asp?id=1004), you compass will be pointing you at a different direction as the time passes by, significantly lowering the usefulness of such an instrument.

You can still use a gyroscopic compass, though, which would not be influenced by the magnetic field.

Comment: The second point is much insightful, I must say. Pole-switching takes a few thousand years and has your poles pointing in weird, not-opposite, rotationally mis-aligned ways, so yeah, enough time to have a story

And the Gyroscopic compass, I learnt something new